# How can I forcibly exclude a nested dependency for NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using `node 0.10.x` and `npm 2.15.0`, I want to forcibly exclude a nested dependency that ends up being installed.

So far I've tried to create `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and manually edited it to remvoe the nested dependency but after running `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` ... I can still see the nested dependency being built for:

```
kerberos@0.0.19 install /.../node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
(node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
```

Comment: Related: `npm install --no-optional`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256960/17823

Answer (score 15):

### npm >= 8.3.0

Using the [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) feature of newer versions of npm it is now possible to prevent a dependency of a dependency from being installed by replacing it with a link to the local file system. It's a bit of a hack, but it works both on Unix and on Windows.

First, make sure that you are using npm 8.3.0 or later. Enter in the command line:

```
npm -v
```

to see the version of npm installed.

Now, looking at the example in the question, let's say one of your dependencies has installed an old version of `mongodb` which in turn has installed `kerberos` in your node_modules folder.

You don't use `kerberos` anyway and you don't want it to be installed by `npm install`, so edit the `"overrides"` section of your package.json file like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "overrides": {
    "kerberos": "../_EXCLUDED_"
  },
  ...
}
```

Be sure to run `npm install` again after this change. This will create a symbolic link (Unix) or a junction (Windows):

`node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos` ->
`node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/_EXCLUDED_`

It is intended that the target of the symlink does not exist: with this, every attempt to load `kerberos` using `require` or `import` will result an easily detectable error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'kerberos'

This should save you from the pain of debugging errors caused by excluding a dependency that is required.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue, and created a dummy package [dry-uninstall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dry-uninstall) to override unused dependencies. Use it in `"overrides"` section of **package.lock**:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "kerberos": "npm:dry-uninstall"
  }
}
```

This is the same hack as in *GOTO 0* answer, but package has empty `index.js`, so code will not fail on `require('kerberos')` or `import`.

Answer (score -1):

The NPM team has provided some suggestions that may also help for situations like this. See:
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/145724408060/dealing-with-problematic-dependencies-in-a

Their suggestion is, essentially, to branch or fork the dependency that is pulling in the dependency you do not want. From your code snippet, I think you want to fork the mongodb module and remove the dependency on kerberos and update loopback-connector-mongodb to use your fork of mongodb.

This answer on a similar question may be helpful when forking the dependencies:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349284/1524989

It would also be possible to substitute a dummy package for the one you want to remove. To do so, create a new package (e.g. `npm init kerberos` ) and update package-lock.json (or npm-shrinkwrap.json, if you prefer) to substitute it for the real kerberos package.