# How to permanently exclude specific transitive dependencies in NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a Vue.js project with only 24 direct dependencies in the `package.json`. That results in 1230 total dependencies in the `package-lock.json`.

One of the transitive dependencies has a license that is not allowed in my organization. I did some research on Google on how to exclude transitive dependencies in NPM, but I couldn't find anything useful.

In Maven (Java world) there is an optional `exclusions` list for each direct dependency. Is there something similar for NPM? How can I permanently remove a transitive dependency from my project?

Comment: Half out of curiosity - What's the "bad" package, and what package is depending on it? After all, if it's a hard dependency, the depending package may break.

Comment: You can resolve to a specific version (only *potentially* useful), or hack the lock file. I don't think you can change the package *itself* w/ resolutions (e.g., replace the package w/ an API-compatible one). But if you exclude it, and it's actually being used, things will break.

Comment: @AKX for example `webpack-chain` (MPL-2.0) is a transitive dependency of `@vue/cli-service`. I figured out that this module is not part of the deliverable, not distributed to customers, that's why it's ok after all. But anyway, in future I might have a transitive dependency with GPL license which I will need to exclude. Not all dependencies are always mandatory. The developer should at least have the option to exclude dependencies, just like in the Java world with Maven. Really don't know why NPM is so limiting.

Comment: @DaveNewton I saw that with Yarn I can resolve transitive dependencies to specific versions. But that doesn't help me if all versions of the module have the same license. That's a cool feature but not really what I was looking for. Thanks for your comment anyway!

Comment: Honestly, your best bet might be a [`postinstall` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) that obliterates or replaces any bad packages from your `node_modules` tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758157 has the answer.


`"overrides": { "yourlib": "../_EXCLUDED_" }`


does the trick if the transitive lib is actually unused, but there may still be unused imports of it that have to be disabled too.